# Pixel 7 Android 13 - what could cause wlan0 to change to wlan1?

Tags: google-pixel, android-13, wlan

I have an FTP server on my phone that auto-starts with Tasker to perform unattended backups.

Recently it stopped working. As I debugged the issue I found errors in the log of "unable to connect to wlan0".  The Wi-Fi connection was fine, so I was puzzled. I finally re-created the SFTP server profile and discovered that wlan0 doesn't exist. The Wi-Fi connection is now wlan1.

That fixed the problem, but I'm curious why wlan0 would suddenly change to wlan1? No OS updates or new apps have been recently installed.

Comment: The interface changed back to wlan0 after a month. This broke the SFTP server again and I had to manually re-configure. I still have no clue what could cause the change in interface name. Apparently I'm the only one? Or maybe nobody else is even aware of their wlan interface name? I see this because I run an SFTP server only when their phone is on a specific Wi-Fi network (with the help of Tasker)